# Returning Value of Grouped Items when using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am trying to use Linq to XML in Visual Studio - C# to pull all of the Elements in an XML file and group them by their value.

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <topTerms>
   <topTerm>Cat</topTerm>
  <topTerm>Dog</topTerm>
  <topTerm>Cat</topTerm>
  <topTerm>Dog</topTerm>
  <topTerm>Cat</topTerm>
  <topTerm>Bird</topTerm>
  <topTerm>Cat</topTerm>
</topTerms>
```

I am then using the following C# code to try and pull the data and group it by value of the topTerm element.

```
var top = 0;
        var topName = "";
        var topTermsUrl = Server.MapPath("XML/topTerms.xml");
        XDocument topTermsFile = XDocument.Load(topTermsUrl);
        var topTermDocuments = topTermsFile.Root
                        .Elements("topTerm")
                        .GroupBy(a => a.Value);
    foreach (var topTerm in topTermDocuments)
    {
        topName = topTerm.Value;
        top = topTerm.Count();
    }
```

However, topTerm.Value is not working. It will count the number of occurrence for each value when I cycle through, but I cannot get the string value being counted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`topTerm` is an [`IGrouping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx), particularly `IGrouping<string, XElement>`. So it has a property `Key` that contains the value by which you grouped:

```
foreach (var topTerm in topTermDocuments)
{
    topName = topTerm.Key; // Key used here
    top = topTerm.Count();
}
```

(I assume that in the full code you do more than overwriting variables in a loop).

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. Thanks! Yes, I will be adding code to add these values to a string within the loop.